# xml is not generated in the correct order by java

Tags: java, xml, xslt-1.0

I am using `xstream` to generate the xml from the java object , below is the xml generated from the java object

```
<brokermail>
  <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <com.absfm.ice.ioa.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
      <InvoiceReference>SM/829709/0315</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>IRMAR157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>2546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>1245.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:07:20.78 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abc</Remarks>
    </com.rbsfm.ice.ioa.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <com.rbsfm.ice.ioa.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
      <InvoiceReference>SM/15</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>I157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>255546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>125545.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:07:20.78 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abERRc</Remarks>
    </com.absfm.ice.ioa.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
</brokermail>
```

but I want the xml to be generated in the below fashion

```
<brokermail>

  <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
   <InvoiceReference>SM/829709/0315</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>IRMAR157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>2546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>1245.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:38:35.110 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abc</Remarks>
     </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>

     <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
        <InvoiceReference>SM/15</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>I157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>255546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>125545.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:38:35.110 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abERRc</Remarks>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>

</brokermail>
```

now as shown just above that I want the xml to be generated in the above fashion which is not happening right now. Can you please advise what changes I need to do in my below pojo to get the xml in the above fashion. Below is my pojo

```
  public class Mail {


           private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();

            public List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> getInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages() {
                return invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;
            }

            public void addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages) {
                this.invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages;
            }
    }
```

and here is the main method call that is happening

Below is the main class through which below xstream is used to generate the xml.

```
InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = new InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage();
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceReference("SM/854565");
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.ABSReference("IRM5454311");
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setCurrency("GBP");
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceAmount(255446);
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setPaidAmount(12445);
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setBalanceAmount(0);
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setValueDate(new Date());
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setRemarks("abc");


        InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1 = new InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage();
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setInvoiceReference("SM/14545");
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.ABSReference("I15745311");
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setCurrency("EUR");
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setInvoiceAmount(2555546);
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setPaidAmount(125545);
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setBalanceAmount(0);
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setValueDate(new Date());
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1.setRemarks("abERRc");

        List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest = new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage);
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1);

        Mail m = new Mail();
        m.addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest);


      XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("brokermail",Mail.class);
        String abc = xstream.toXML(m);
        System.out.println(abc);
```

folks please advise what changes i need to do in my above pojos to get the desired xml as i have shown

Answer (score 0):

In order to worakaround the problem and have a relevant item name for your collection items instead of having the fully qualified class name of each:

- Annotate your item collection instance field with `@XStreamImplicit` using a suitable name:

  ```
  public class Mail {

    @XStreamImplicit( itemFieldName = "invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage" )
    private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;
    //...
  }
  ```
- Before serializing your object, call the `#processAnnotations(Class)` method on your `xstream` instance to trigger metadata processing:

  ```
  Mail m = new Mail();
  m.addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest);

  XStream xstream = new XStream();
  xstream.alias("brokermail", Mail.class);
  xstream.processAnnotations(Mail.class);
  String abc = xstream.toXML(m);
  System.out.println(abc);
  ```

Comment: xstream.processAnnotations(Mail.class); is giving compliation problems indication to cast it in object please advise how to proceed

Comment: Could you please post your error stack? I can't see where the cast problem could came from as the method argument is of type `Class`, and the method has no return value...